# auto export to ICS when specifc orgmode file is saved?

Tags: org-mode

i would like to have a way to save a function every X hours and to a user defined directory
so far i have this

`(defun z/save-meeting-to-ics ()
    "If the current file is in '~/.dotfiles', the code blocks are tangled"
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name)
                 (expand-file-name "/home/zeltak/org/files/agenda/meetings.org"))
      (org-icalendar-export-to-ics)
      (message "exported to ics")))`

this does save the org file "meetings.org" to an ICS file in the same

folder as the file. but i want to do 2 additional things:
1)save the resulting ICS file to a different directory
2)run this function every X hours (lets say every 2 hours)

any clue?

Comment: Please do not sign off posts with "thanks" or your name/initial (it's the norm on these sites not to put them in).

Comment: edited above question as requested dan.

Comment: So i have this now ```  (defun z/save-meeting-to-ics ()
    "If the current file is in '~/.dotfiles', the code blocks are tangled"
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name)
                 (expand-file-name "/home/zeltak/org/files/agenda/meetings.org"))
 (rename-file (org-icalendar-export-to-ics) "/home/zeltak/org/files/export/kcal.ics")
      (message "exported to ics")))

(run-with-timer 0 (* 30 60) 'z/save-meeting-to-ics)``` yet i still cant get the ics file to be created niether when i save the meeting.org file nor every 600 seconds. what am i missing here?